# Faulty logic when summing large integers?

Tags: arithmetic, project-euler

This  is in relation to the Euler Problem $13$ from http://www.ProjectEuler.net.

Work out the first ten digits of the sum of the following one-hundred $50$-digit numbers.

$37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250$

Now, this was my thinking:

I can freely discard the last fourty digits and leave the last ten.

$0135740250$

And then simply sum those. This would be large enough to be stored in a $64$-bit data-type and a lot easier to compute. However, my answer isn't being accepted, so I'm forced to question my logic.

However, I don't see a problem. The last fourty digits will never make a difference because they are at least a magnitude of $10$ larger than the preceding values and therefore never carry backwards into smaller areas. Is this not correct?

Comment: I think you're counting from the wrong end...

Comment: This problem is actually small enough to use a BigNum implementation, like BigInteger in .NET 4.0.

Comment: @Morrison: What do you mean? The smallest numbers always start at the right?

@Gietzen: I think I'll try that with my next approach, thanks for the idea.

Comment: "First" is ambiguous. Ten leftmost or ten rightmost? I believe the people at Project Euler want the former.

Comment: They are asking for first ten digits so you need to calculate the whole answer and then show the first 10 digits as answer

Comment: Maybe it's my eye-sight, but I see only one number, not one-hundred. What is being added? Also if you discard the _last_ $40$ digits, it is the _first_ $10$ that remain.

Comment: @Calc1DropOut: That edit was *completely* unnecessary. It did not provide an actual improvement in readability and just bumped a three years old post to the top of the front page. Please avoid these in the future, front page time is an extremely expensive resource.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you were supposed to find the *last* ten digits, you could just ignore the first 40 digits of each number. However you're supposed to find the *first* ten digits, so that doesn't work. And you can't just ignore the last digits of each number either because those *can* carry over.

Answer (score 6):

First you are doing it in the wrong end, second, the statement in general is still not correct.

for example:

```
9999999999
1000000001
```

Say if you want the first 2 digits,
you will get 10 if you discard the last 2 digit and do the sum.
The right answer is 11